# set dropdown box and display last selected item in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

i need to populate a select box with values and 
i need to select box to display last selected item(from db).The goal is to let the user update the details.
And i have more than 30 items in the select box.i am new to php ..help me

Comment: what you try ??  please show some code that you try.

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectedValue = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : 'none';
$options = $db->query('...');
...
...
<select name="foo">
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$option->value?>"<?= $option->value === $selectedValue ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?=$option->value?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```